# Warning by extending LinkedList class in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to extend LinkdList in Java through the following class definition:

```
public class Roster extends LinkedList<Teammate>{

}
```

but I get the following warning by doing so:

```
The serializable class Roster does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long
```

What does that mean and how can I remove the warning?

Comment: Read java doc - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/what-is-a-serialversionuid-and-why-should-i-use-it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warning means you're not doing what you "agree" to do when you extend that class. That class trusts that you'll have a `static final serialVersionUID field of type long` in your class if you extend it. That's because it `implements Serializable` which is an interface requiring this variable.

To supress the warning add:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
```

above the line where you declare the class (`public class Foo`)

To fix the warning declare the variable as follows:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1812107715815332895L;
```

And make sure the long you use is randomly generated.

Eclipse allows both of these options as a quick-fix by clicking on the yellow lightbulb next to the line number.

Comment: Thanks.  I did not see that I was implementing the Serializable Interface with this class.  I'm quite the Java noob in some respects, so I'm still learning all of the ins-and-outs of the java docs.  It's easy to not have the greatest bearing at first....

Comment: @WildBill You're welcome. Please accept my answer as the correct one if it answered your question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

> The serialVersionUID is a universal version identifier for a
>   Serializable class. Deserialization uses this number to ensure that a
>   loaded class corresponds exactly to a serialized object. If no match
>   is found, then an InvalidClassException is thrown.

To fix this declare a static unique id in the class -

`private static final long serialVersionUID = 75264722950069776147L;`  // unique id